# nuget.server nuget package exception

Tags: nuget, nuget-server

I am trying to run Nuget.Server on my visual studio 2013 right after adding that nuget package to my project.

Error:

```
    [ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values..
Paramter name: site]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +303

[HttpException (0x80004005): Specified argument was out of the range of valid values..
שם פרמטר: site]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9915300
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the problem was different.

I couldn't start any web application on VS 2013 and windows 7 Home Premium until I have have enabled the local IIS server.

The problem is addressed here:

[ASP.net Forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1845408.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

which version of NuGet.Server package have you installed? Did you install it to asp.net web application?

A document about how to create a remote feed - http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds